# Can Not Open Executable Jar file by Double Clicking

Tags: java

I want to run an Executable Jar file by double clicking from its folder, not from the NetBeans IDE. But I cannot do that. I'm attaching an Image file also, in case you find it difficult to understand. Kindly help.

[image]

Comment: If you run it from the commandline with `java -jar JavaApplication3.jar` what message do you get?

Comment: "no main manifest attribute, in JavaApplication3.jar" this is the message from the CMD window.

Comment: Kayaman I'm sorry to say that it's absolutely ok, if someone doesn't have any idea of certain things. There is no need to hide behind words for that. It's kind of vague, the way you answered. You could have chosen not to answer rather. Would have made no difference!!! Google!! I mean really! Why wasting time here in Stackoverlfow then??

Comment: Why indeed? You could solve your problems quicker by using Google. Here's an [example query](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+your+problem+here&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+your+problem+here) that'll solve pretty much all your problems. That way you won't have to wait around for answers, until you run into something **really** tricky. There's nothing wrong with solving your own problems instead of being completely dependent on other people's help.